# how to make gdb output only to the file

Tags: c++, gdb, sh, tcsh

I'm not very into unix/linux, I'm using rhat linux with sh, tcsh shells.
What I'm trying to do is to debug lifecycle of the object of the class by breaking on it's default, copy c-tors, on d-tor and on operator=; move operations are not defined neither by compiler or me. I break on these functions and printf some lines and also print backtrace

```
br /project/src/some_file.c:408
commands
silent
printf "<%p> D E F A U L T c-tor bt:\n", this
bt
cont
end
```

The thing is there're a lot objects of this class, so there is a lot of output, and nothing helps me to disable output to the terminal, so I want see gdb output only in the file, not in the shell. Is it possible to achieve using sh or tcsh? - I can't really impact on the environment and use some other debugger or shell. The reason I want to disable any output from gdb and process being debugged to the shell is because I believe it slows down gdb and execution of the debugged process, which breaks behavior of debugged application. 
Using gdb 8.1. I tried logging options of gdb, redirecting output by

```
 run > somefile
```

and I tried to run gdb like this

```
gdb -p 1000 -x breakpoint.txt     | tee somefile.txt
```

Thanks many times!

Comment: Have you tried the [logging options](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Logging-Output.html)?

Comment: @lubgr Yep, I added what I've tried to the end of description. Thanks.

Comment: You can send commands like `gdb -ex "run" -ex "bt" -ex "q" ./exe`.  That will execute everything and exit gdb. You can redirect the output to a file in a regular way `> myfile.txt`.

Comment: @Yuki I helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this link has various option for logging

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html

simple one is

```
set logging file file
```

Change the name of the current logfile. The default logfile is gdb.txt.

then

```
set logging on
```

Enable logging.